# What are the conditions for switching the order of infinite product and infinite sum?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

This is a problem I have come across while reading statistical mechanics of particles by Mehran Kardar. We have this expression in the derivation of a theorem that expresses moments in terms of cumulants.
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-ik)^m}{m!}\langle x^m \rangle=\exp\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-ik)^n}{n!}\langle x^n \rangle_c\right]=\prod_n\sum_{p_n}\left[\frac{(-ik)^{np_n}}{p_n!}\left(\frac{\langle x^n \rangle_c}{n!}\right)^{p_n}\right]$$
I understood this far but immidiatly after this the author matches the power of $(-ik)^m$ from both side and derives,
$$\langle x^m \rangle=\sum_{\{p_n\}}m!\prod_n\frac{1}{p_n!(n!)^{p_n}}\langle x^n \rangle^{p_n}_c$$
Here the sum is restricted such that $\sum np_n=m$. It seems to me that the author just switches the product and sum. Because then I can calculate as follows,
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-ik)^m}{m!}\langle x^m \rangle=\sum_{p_n}\prod_n\left[\frac{(-ik)^{np_n}}{p_n!}\left(\frac{\langle x^n \rangle_c}{n!}\right)^{p_n}\right]$$
$$\implies\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-ik)^m}{m!}\langle x^m \rangle=\sum_{p_n}\prod_n\left[\frac{1}{p_n!}\left(\frac{\langle x^n \rangle_c}{n!}\right)^{p_n}\right](-ik)^{\sum np_n}$$

Which leads to the derived expression when power of $(-ik)^m$ is matched from both sides.

So my question is, can we always do that? if we can't then what are the conditions that when satisfied the order of product and sum can be switched? Or how do you think the author did it?